# comparing two arrays and getting the data as it was

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am storing data like this in `scope` variable as

```
$scope.myData = 
    {
      "firstName": "rocky",
      "lastName": "P",
      "place": "Koraput",
      "education": [
        {
          "id": "764006"
        },
        {
          "id": "764001"
        }
      ],
      "email": "rockyp123@gmail.com",
      "id": "46ads75asda7s6d57ad"
    }
```

Case: Suppose I am updating this data. I added education to it and then i click `cancel`. How to remove the currently added education on click on cancel and retrieve the data that is only two education as mentioned above on click of `edit user`?

Comment: Please edit the question. It is not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: You can have a copy of your initial array when hitting edit and restore to that on cancel maybe?

Comment: Use `.push()` in adding data to your education, this will add the data at the end of your array. If you cancel, then use`.pop()`. This will remove the data you added last.

Comment: @tanmay, it worked. It is a silly thing to be asked.

Comment: @NarasinghaPadhi happens with every one of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should keep two separate objects, one that is the original, unchanged object, and the other that is used for editing. Once the user clicks, say `save`, only then should you overwrite the first object with the second. Once you click `cancel`, you can simply revert the value of the editable object back to a clone of the original data.

You'd start off by cloning the first object into a new, second object:

```
// Your original data (unchanged)
$scope.myData = { /* ... */ };

// Your object for editing purposes
$scope.myDataClone = clone($scope.myData);

$scope.cancel = function() {
  // reset the 'editable' clone to the unchanged value of myData
  $scope.myDataClone = clone($scope.myData);
}

$scope.save = function() {
  // Once the user accepts their changes, you can simply
  // set the value of myData to a clone of the edited data.
  // This will ensure you are not just creating a new pointer
  // from myData to myDataClone, which would cause myData
  // to change if you make subsequent requests to myDataClone.
  $scope.myData = clone($scope.myDataClone);
}

// A clone function which takes an object and returns an exact
// replica as a new object with a unique memory reference
function clone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Comment: Keeping a raw copy and comparing it while cancelling works for me.

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Yes. Instead of clone(), i used angular.copy() @Danny Bull

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you've figured out the solution. Should you mark this answer as correct?

Comment: I did it though i have less reputation.

Comment: @NarasinghaPadhi You didn't. Accept an answer is clicking on the green mark at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.copy()` method to have a copy object of original array and just make a reference to it when you ***cancel***:

```js
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {
    "firstName": "rocky",
    "lastName": "P",
    "place": "Koraput",
    "education": [{
      "id": "764006"
    }, {
      "id": "764001"
    }],
    "email": "rockyp123@gmail.com",
    "id": "46ads75asda7s6d57ad"
  };
  $scope.copy = angular.copy($scope.myData.education);
  $scope.onAdd = function() {
    $scope.myData.education.push({
      id: $scope.myData.education.length
    });

  };
  $scope.onCancel = function() {
    $scope.myData.education = $scope.copy; // <----reset to original
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <pre>{{myData.education}}</pre>
  <button ng-click="onAdd()">+</button>
  <button ng-click="onCancel()">X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove using id

```
  $scope.myData = 
  {
    "firstName": "rocky",
    "lastName": "P",
    "place": "Koraput",
    "education": [
    {
      "id": "764006"
    },
    {
      "id": "764001"
    }
    ],
    "email": "rockyp123@gmail.com",
    "id": "46ads75asda7s6d57ad"
  };

  //Remove specific item
  $scope.onCancel = function(cancelId){

      for(var i in $scope.myData.education){
       if($scope.myData.education[i].id==cancelId){
        $scope.myData.education.splice(i, 1);;
        break;
      }
    }

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the main object and while cancel you can update the main object with the copy

and while saving update the copy with new object

like

```
$scope.myData = 
  {
    "firstName": "rocky",
    "lastName": "P",
    "place": "Koraput",
    "education": [
    {
      "id": "764006"
    },
    {
      "id": "764001"
    }
    ],
    "email": "rockyp123@gmail.com",
    "id": "46ads75asda7s6d57ad"
  };
$scope.copymyData  = angular.copy($scope.myData);
$scope.cancel = function(){
  $scope.myData = angular.copy($scope.copymyData);
}
$scope.save = function(){
   $scope.copymyData  = angular.copy($scope.myData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using push and pop,

**HTML:**

```
  <button ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
   $scope.myData =[];
   $scope.myData = [
   {
     "firstName": "rocky",
     "lastName": "P",
     "education":'MBA',
     "place": "Koraput",
     "email": "rockyp123@gmail.com",
     "id": "46ads75asda7s6d57ad"
   }];

   $scope.myData.push({
      education : 'BE'
   })

   $scope.cancel = function(){
     var lastElement = $scope.myData.pop();
   }
```